# How to hide /mnt/ from Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: linux

So I recently installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux on my PC and everytime I use the `pwd` command, I would see the `/mnt/` portion added to the path name. Here is an example of what I am referring to.

```
Michael@X556AUK:~ $ pwd
/mnt/c/Users/Michael
```

Is there any way of hiding the `/mnt/` portion of the pathname. I was able to remove the `/cygdrive/` portion from my Cygwin pathnames in the past and I would like to know how to do something similar on WSL for `/mnt/`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to a bind mount. In linux it will:

```
remount part of the file hierarchy somewhere else.
   The call is:

          mount --bind olddir newdir

   After this call the same contents are accessible in two places.
```

So I think you want `mount --bind /mnt /`

---

A link is another idea, but it might just make the path longer instead of shorter.